# Excel: Determine if value exists in third column of pivot table, based on 2 preceding columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a list of user's attributes nearly 10,000 long. Each user has multiple attributes, based on their department and job code. Looks a little something like this:

```
| USER   | DEPT   | JOB   | ATTRIBUTE   |

| User A | Dept 1 | Job 1 | Attribute 2 |
| User A | Dept 1 | Job 1 | Attribute 3 |
| User B | Dept 2 | Job 1 | Attribute 1 |
| User B | Dept 2 | Job 1 | Attribute 2 |
| User C | Dept 1 | Job 2 | Attribute 3 |
| User C | Dept 1 | Job 2 | Attribute 4 |
| User C | Dept 1 | Job 2 | Attribute 5 |
| User C | Dept 1 | Job 2 | Attribute 6 |
```

Where "Job 1" can have different attributes based on which department job 1 is in. I also have a pivot table in a different workbook that defines which attributes a job code should have for each department. I need a formula that will take the attribute in the row, and compare it to the pivot table to see if that attribute is associate with that department and job code combination.

## EDIT

I am no longer using a pivot table, and have taken all information from the pivot table and populated the worksheet (so there is a data entry for every column in the row.

I have taken the suggested formula and updated to reflect my page titles, however I only receive back "Not associated for everything.

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX('Roles'!C:C,MATCH(B2&C2&D2,'Roles'!A:A&'Roles'!B:B&'Roles'!C:C,0)),"Not Associated")
```

If I understand correctly, this is checking to confirm there is a match of B2 in column A of Roles, a match of C2 in column B of Roles and a match of D2 in Column c of Roles. If that is correct, there is a match for each, but am still returning Not Associated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pivot table is Worksheet `PivotTable` starting in column A with the following fields

```
Dept | Job | Attribute
```

and your referenced data is in columns A:D of the current sheet use this formula:

```
=IfError(Index(PivotTable!C:C,Match(A2&B2&C2,PivotTable!A:A&PivotTable!B:B&PivotTable!C:C,0),"Not Associated")
```

This will return "Not Associated" if the attribute is not associated witht the Dept and Job, or will return the attribute if it is associated.